# Uncheck checkbox when I check another one

Tags: javascript, html

Hey I have two issues with this following code.

First of all when I check the checkbox number 3 it automatically checks number 2, I only want that if I check it my self (Like when I check checkbox number 2).
The second issue is I can't uncheck a checkbox after checking it.

```js
var cbs = document.getElementsByName("test");

function demo(obj) {
        var hzp = cbs[1];
    var ht = cbs[2];
   for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
       if(cbs[i].value == hzp.value || cbs[i].value === ht.value) {
        if(cbs[i].value == obj.value) {
          if(cbs[i].checked && hzp.checked || ht.checked) {
            hzp.checked = true;
            ht.checked = true;
          }
         }
       }
       cbs[i].checked = false;
       
    }
    obj.checked = true;

}
```

```html
checkbox 1 <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="demo1" value="demo01" onClick="demo(this)">
checkbox 2  <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="demo2" value="demo02" onClick="demo(this)">
checkbox 3  <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="demo3" value="demo03" onClick="demo(this)">
checkbox 4  <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="demo" value="demo04" onClick="demo(this)">
```

Comment: are you trying to make checkboxes act like radio buttons?

Comment: Yes for number one and number 4 I want them to behave like radio buttons but for number 2 and 3 I want them to act as checkboxs.

Answer (score 1):

```
e.target.value==cbs[0].value ?
```

if clicked input has value of demo01

```
cbs[3].checked=false
```

set demo04 checked to false

```
: e.target.value==cbs[3].value
```

else if clicked input has value of demo04

```
? cbs[0].checked=false
```

set demo01 checked to false

```
: null
```

else, nothing...

```js
var cbs = document.getElementsByName("test")

cbs.forEach( test => {test.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  e.target.value==cbs[0].value ? cbs[3].checked=false : e.target.value==cbs[3].value ? cbs[0].checked=false : null
  })
})
```

```html
checkbox 1  <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="demo1" value="demo01" >
checkbox 2  <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="demo2" value="demo02">
checkbox 3  <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="demo3" value="demo03">
checkbox 4  <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="demo" value="demo04">
```

Answer (score 0):

Look closely - this is not jQuery.

This gets your bigger job simplified - that of making the checkboxes work like radio buttons.  Now, you should be able to quite easily add logic to make it do the rest of what you want.

The basic idea is to:

a. Trap when any checkbox is clicked
b. Store the checked checkbox value
c. Cache the checkbox itself (so we can turn it back on)
d. Uncheck ALL checkboxes
e. Re-check the one the user just checked.
f. Update div / variable with the stored value

*Now, just add some additional (e.g. storedVal) variables to keep track of additional checkboxes.*

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
var storedVal = '';

$$('input').forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    storedVal = e.target.value;
    let ckcb = e.target;
    uncheckAll();
    ckcb.checked = true;
    console.log(storedVal);
    $('#msg').innerText = storedVal;
  });
});

const uncheckAll = () => {
  $$('input').forEach((el) => {
    el.checked = false;
  });
}
```

```css
#msg{
  position:absolute;
  top:70px;
  right:30px;
  font-size:2rem;
  padding:10px;
  background:wheat;
}
```

```html
checkbox 1 <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="demo1" value="demo01">
checkbox 2  <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="demo2" value="demo02">
checkbox 3  <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="demo3" value="demo03">
checkbox 4  <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="demo" value="demo04">
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Comment: This is a very complex way of creating what radio buttons do with far less code. This also does not achieve what OP is asking for.

Comment: There are multiple reasons to make checkboxes behave like radio buttons - even just as an exercise. But that exercise has multiple applications in the real world, I have found (repeatedly). Who knows why the OP wants to do this? Perhaps he has a reason you haven't thought of. *Personally, I found the above algorithm very helpful when it was shown to me.*

Comment: It also does not achieve what they are looking for.